# Pushing mysql to heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku, taps

I succesfully ported to Django app to heroku, and now I just need to push the database.
I tried with:

```
heroku db:push mysql://root@localhost:themedb
```

and got the following error:

```
Loaded Taps v0.3.23
 !    Invalid database url
```

I'm pretty sure mysql://root@localhost:themedb is wrong but I dont know what part of it is.
The database has no password so I skipped the password.

I appreciate any help.

UPDATE: 
As suggested by hgmnz I did:

```
heroku db:push mysql://root@localhost/themedb
```

but got the following:

```
Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: no such file to load -- mysql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `heroku db:push mysql://root@localhost/themedb`, and I'd like to point you at [valkyrie](https://github.com/ddollar/valkyrie), the likely successor of taps.

Comment: That worked, *partially*. Now I'm getting a Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: no such file to load -- mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try running `heroku config` on the command line - do you have a `DATABASE_URL` config var for your database? If so, try pushing with that instead.

If you don't have a `DATABASE_URL` config var, have you added a mysql database to your app? If not you should first add a database from https://addons.heroku.com/ (or from the command line, if you prefer). If you have already added a database you may need to run `heroku addons:add {addon-name}` again from the command line to make sure the config var gets added.